# Why i am unable to clear the form using classes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Onreset</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        Username:
        <input type="text" class="abc"><br><br> 
        Password:
        <input type="password" class="def"><br><br> 
        <input type="button" onclick="myfun()" value="clear">
    </form>
    <script>
        function myfun()
        {
            var a = document.getElementsByClassName('abc').value;
            a.value = "";
            var b = document.getElementsByClassName('def').value;
            b.value = "";
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have cleared the above form with reset function. That is apart, but I need to clear the above form using class names only... Where is the mistake I'm doing in the above code? Please help me!

Comment: `var a = document.getElementsByClassName('abc')`

Comment: what is the problem with reset() method?

Comment: My question is can i do it using classes in j.s or not..i came to know that we can...but i m finding difficulty somewhere

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array. you cant use `.value` for an array.Better go with `ID` or do like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/q4s7p6x8/) . Too many down votes in short span for OP as well as answers :O

Comment: I doesnt care about down votes sir, i need to know where actually the problem is with classes..i was digging since 2 hrs but unable to crack it! seeking for a help as i am an beginner

Comment: for some reason all the answers below got down voted (and then deleted) even though pretty much all of them gave you the correct thing to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code it doesnt matter, how many elements with same class name you have.

```
<script>
    function myfun()
    {
        var a = document.getElementsByClassName('abc');

        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i].value = "";
        }

        var b = document.getElementsByClassName('def');

        for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            b[i].value = "";
        }
    }
</script>
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/legionar/y8k5gqaf/)

If you will have only one element with same class name, then here is the code without the loop:

```
<script>
    function myfun()
    {
        var a = document.getElementsByClassName('abc');
        a[0].value = "";

        var b = document.getElementsByClassName('def');
        b[0].value = "";
    }
</script>
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/legionar/y8k5gqaf/1/)

Comment: Sure. Are you sure, you will have only one element with same class name?

Comment: Check my DEMO in answer, its working without the loop.

Comment: Its working sir! great! but a[0] is an array! am i right sir

Comment: `a` is an array, because function `getElementsByClassName` returns an array. `a[0]` is not an array, its element of array.

Comment: It's bymistake...Sorry For that sir! Apologies

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94271/discussion-between-manoj-karthik-and-legionar).

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a list. If you are sure there is only 1 element with that classname just get the first element from that list.

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("abc")[0];
```

Comment: for your other one you need to do. `var b = document.getElementsByClassName('def')[0]`

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one element with `abc` and `def` class names, you can do the following:

```
function myfun()
{
    document.getElementsByClassName('abc')[0].value = '';
    document.getElementsByClassName('def')[0].value = '';
}
```

[Code in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6gzKSfsMzU341a3SKQKg)

If you want to reset value of all fields, you can use the following:

```
<input type="reset" value="clear">
```

Comment: This is ok if there is only one element for each class.

Comment: @Vithozor  in the question there is only one element for each class

Comment: Yes, I know and the form in the question does not contain multiple element of same class.

Comment: Read the question again! "I Have cleared the above form with reset function. That is apart, but I need to clear the above form using class names only.."

Comment: In the answer, I've shown another way to reset the form so that it may help others also.

Comment: @Nayan...Please Help Me With Classes Sir, i've done already with type 'reset'

Comment: @ManojKarthik I've added sample code in plunker. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByClassName('abc') returns an object(array) of matching classes, hence you may have to specify the position of the class you're referring to in that object(array)

Try this:

```
function myFunction()
    {
        var a = document.getElementsByClassName('abc')[0];
        a.value = "";
        var b = document.getElementsByClassName('def')[0];
        b.value = "";
    }
```

[Working Demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/exbnq6Lo/)